# wordpress: how to include a php file in frontend AND admin area (Fatal error: Cannot redeclare myfunction())

Tags: wordpress, include, declare

I have some troubles to include a file called myplugin_functions.php

This php file contains functions that are required to make some functions work in the wordpress admin area. For that reason I include this file in backend pages using:

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'myplugin_functions.php');
```

This works perfectly.

When I do the same thing on frontend pages, the frontend can access these functions. Great.

But when I then navigate to the backend I get an error message

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare myfunction() (previously declared in /www/htdocs/...) in /www/htdocs/..../myplugin_functions.php on line 28
```

include_once() makes the problem vanish. But I think wordpress doesn't like including the same php functions for frontend and backend.

Do you know why?
What is the best practice to get around this?

Thank you?

Comment: may be problem in code

Comment: the problem is that it is included multiple times. when I use include_once() the problem vanishes. But I dont think that this is best practice

Comment: you are right, use include_once(), yes we don't do like this.

Comment: @sprytechies: Why dont you like this? I would like to write DRY code, this is why I dont want to repeat identical code lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress uses the same functions for frontend and backend.....you're prob getting confused with ajax functions which are hooked seperately.

If you are including the file within a function, use require_once/ include_once. If you want the functions to be available to the entire directory, place require_once in your theme functions or plugin file file but then don't include when using functions.

require_once / include_once are actually good practice btw :)